# MySQL: WHERE TimeStamp after today

Tags: mysql

I would like to `SELECT` 5 Items `WHERE` unix_timestamp is after today.

**Example**:
unix_timestamp (here not the format):

```
 15.08.2013
 18.08.2013
 21.08.2013
 27.08.2013
 30.08.2013
```

**MySQL**: `SELECT * WHERE unix_timestamp is today or after today and ORDER BY unix_timestamp with LIMIT 0,5`

**MySQL Result must be** items with the unix_timestamp:

```
18.08.2013
21.08.2013
27.08.2013
30.08.2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should actually work ([**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65f7b/5)):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp, '%m.%d.%Y') as `Date` FROM dates WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp, '%m.%d.%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m.%d.%Y') ORDER BY unix_timestamp Limit 5;
```

I've assumed that because you have named your column `unix_timestamp`, your date is actually stored in that format (eg. 1376825624).

Note, that I would consider to change the name of `unix_timestamp` because there is allready a function in MySQL called `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM FOO
   WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP >= NOW() ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP Limit 5;
```

`NOW()` Return the current date and time

If the UNIX_TIMESTAMP  column contains the data in date format as per the example then instead of `NOW()` you can use `CURRENT_DATE()`.

i.e.

```
 SELECT * FROM FOO
    WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP Limit 5;
```

`CURRENT_DATE()` Return the current date

[Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: This will be >= "*now*" which is not the same as >= "*today*".